# How to change background color of only this section which mark at logo

Tags: magento2, backend, logo

[image]

How to change background color of only this section which mark at logo

Comment: Do you have any custom module?

Comment: did you mean this part ? http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e7611b890

Comment: Yes perfect. @AnilSuthar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In admin `styles.css` CSS file, add this class :

```
.menu-wrapper .logo {
  background: #900;
}
```

Change background as per your requirement

Comment: could tell me where it is file located to add this code?

Comment: `/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css`. BUT yes you should create an admin theme and copy this file to that theme. Then apply changes

Comment: It's working..@ Anil Suthar  How to change Image height and width of that logo?

Comment: .menu-wrapper .logo img{ height: 60px; max-width: none; width: 100%; }